# java extrack only needed numbers

Tags: java, numbers, format, extract

I have a *sample* string:

```
Today 2014 g. and i need buy 4135 g. coca-cola and 632.35 g bread and 7,3 g. salt. Notes by 1996
```

***Notes:***

1. **g** may be **with dot** at end and may be **without dot** at end
2. The **2014 g.** it is a year and may be format **20xx g.** or **19xx g**. only

***Need:***

But I need extract **4135 g.** and **632.35 g** and **7,3 g.** only!!!!

If we find 20xx (with or not **g.** at end) or 19xx (with or not **g.** at end) - this make igore! (dont extract!)

Please, help me please for regex string (for java)

Comment: And what if you have 2014 g. of something?

Comment: if 2014 g. - this is YEAR and we need ignore it. I need igore 1900-1999 and 2000-2099 - this all is YEAR for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex can do that for you:

```
\b(?!19|20)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+g\.?\b
```

Ie, in a java regex:

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN
    = Pattern.compile("\\b(?!19|20)(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)\\s+g\\.?\\b");
```

Create a `Matcher` from your input, cycle with `.find()` and extract `.group(1)` for each match:

```
final Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(input);

while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Decomposition of the regex:

```
\b            # Find a position where we have a word limit, then
(?!19|20)     # find a position where we don't have "19" or "20" following, then
(             # begin capturing group
  \d+         # one or more digits, followed by
  (?:         # begin non capturing group
    \.\d+     # one dot, followed by one or more digits
  )?          # end none capturing group, zero or one time,
)             # end capturing group, followed by
\s+           # one or more spaces, followed by
g\.?          # "g", then a literal dot, zero or one time, followed by
\b            # a word anchor again
```